# How do I display multiple tables within a view using ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I am trying to display multiple data tables in one window but only one table is displayed. For now I am only using testing purposes to print out the same table more than once but it only displays once.

what I have tried to do is under this piece of code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">    
    <div id="live_data"></div>                 
</div>
```

try to display another table the same way

```
<div class="table-responsive">   
    <div id="live_data2"></div>                 
</div>
```

this is the code that I have for index:

```
<html>  
      <head>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">   
                     <div id="live_data"></div>                 
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      function fetch_data()  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#live_data').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }
      ///////added this to try and display same table again//////
      function fetch_data()  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#live_data2').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }
      ///////added this to try and display same table again//////  
      fetch_data();  
      $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){  
           var first_name = $('#first_name').text();  
           var last_name = $('#last_name').text();  
           if(first_name == '')  
           {  
                alert("Enter First Name");  
                return false;  
           }  
           if(last_name == '')  
           {  
                alert("Enter Last Name");  
                return false;  
           }  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"insert.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     fetch_data();  
                }  
           })  
      });
 });  
 </script>
```

my select.php file has:

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db");  
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sample ORDER BY id DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                     <th width="40%">First Name</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Last Name</th>  
                     <th width="10%">Delete</th>  
                </tr>';  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                     <td class="first_name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["first_name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="last_name" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>  
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '  
           <tr>  
                <td></td>  
                <td id="first_name" contenteditable></td>  
                <td id="last_name" contenteditable></td>  
                <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
           </tr>  
      ';  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
                     </tr>';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
      </div>';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

Comment: You created two functions with the same name, that is most likely causing the issue. Try renaming one of them, then call each function separately like: fetch_data(); fetch_data2();

Comment: yes, that was the issue `fetch_data()` was the problem.